# How do I exactly solve this GCD?

Tags: c++, algorithm

https://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXGCD

Chef has a set consisting of N integers. Chef calls a subset of this set to be good if the subset has two or more elements. He denotes all the good subsets as S1, S2, S3, ... , S2N-N-1. Now he represents the GCD of the elements of each good subset Si as Gi.
Chef wants to find the maximum Gi.

Input

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows."
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N denoting the number of elements in the set. The second line contains N space-separated integers A1, A2, ..., AN denoting the elements of the set.

Output

For each test case, output the maximum Gi

My solution:

1. I generate all possible subsets of the given set.
2. I calculate the GCD of each set using Euclid's algorithm
3. I tried to find the maximum of all of them.

This is my code for making all possible subsets:

```
vector< vector<int> > getAllSubsets(vector<int> set)
{
    vector< vector<int> > subset;
    vector<int> empty;
    subset.push_back( empty );

    for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++)
    {
        vector< vector<int> > subsetTemp = subset;

        for (int j = 0; j < subsetTemp.size(); j++)
            subsetTemp[j].push_back( set[i] );

        for (int j = 0; j < subsetTemp.size(); j++)
            subset.push_back( subsetTemp[j] );
    }
    return subset;
}
```

However, I get TLE while going with this approach. Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: With these kinds of problems, you usually need a tiny little bit of mathematics. Say I tell you that GCD (48, 72) = 24. What can you say about GCD (48, 72, x) for an arbitrary x, or GCD (48, 72, x, y, z) for arbitrary x, y, z? After answering this, think about the implications. Is there any reason to examine _all_ good sets?

Comment: I reached the conclusion that if GCD(x,y) is 1, then GCD of any superset containing (x,y) will be 1. But how is that useful to me? I couldn't really use it anywhere.

Comment: @gnasher729, so how do I do it?

Comment: That's a small subset of the implications. Think more?

Answer (score 2):

One optimization is that you never need to consider subsets larger than 2 elements. This is because if you add another element, the GCD can only **decrease**.

This leads to an `O(n^2)` algorithm. The problem statement says that `n` can be as large as `100 000`, so we need to do even better.

The problem also says that the given values are at most `500 000`, so the GCD cannot exceed this.

Let `count[i] = how many times the value i appears in the array`.

Then we can apply something similar to the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes): for a fixed value `v`, see if you can find two multiples of `v` (sum of count[multiple_of_v] > 1). If you can, then you can have a GCD of `v`. Keep track of the max you can find.

Pseudocode:

```
V = max(given array)
cnt[i] = how many times value i occurs in given array

for v = V down to 1:
  num_multiples_v = 0
  for j = v up to V:
    num_multiples_v += cnt[j]

  if num_multiples_v > 1: # TODO: break the inner loop when this is true
    print v as solution
    return
```

Complexity will be `O(V log log V)`, which should be very fast.

Comment: and if the question would have been to find GCD's of all possible subsets of a set, then, would your approach would have worked? I mean, remove the return statement?

Comment: Though your approach seems excellent, but can't I find all possible subsets of a given set of numbers in an efficient manner?

Comment: @Raj A set with n elements has `n!` possible subsets. You can't get `n!` results with less than `n!` steps, and this is *slow*.

Comment: @Raj that's quite a different problem, and I'm not sure what you mean be "find the GCDs of all possible subsets of a set". That reduces to just finding the GCD of the given set (because the subsets will just repeat parts of it), which you can do in `O(n)`. If you mean find the GCD of each subset, you can do no better than `O(2^n)`, because you must at least print / return that many values. Regardless, it's a different question. Please post another question if you have a followup. You can link this as related if you want, but it should be self contained.

Comment: @IVlad, how can I do it then? It will be a great help if you can tell me that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Raj do what? I'm not clear on what your new problem is, and you should ask a new question for it anyway.

Comment: @Ivlad, If I am to find the GCD of each of the subset, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Raj the easiest way to generate subsets is to count in binary from 0 to `2^n - 1`: a 1 bit means that you take the number in that position, and a 0 bit means you don't. Then compute the GCD of the subset using `gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c)`.

Comment: But won't that exceed the time limit if the total possible numbers can be upto 10^5 as well?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all subsets.

Some basic properties of gcd:

```
gcd(a,b) == gcd(b,a)
gcd(a,b) <= a  
gcd(a,b) <= b  
gcd(a,b,c) == gcd(a,gcd(b,c)) == gcd(gcd(a,b),c)
```

and with this, it's easy to show that

```
gcd(a,b) >= gcd(a,b,c) >= gcd(a,b,c,d)...
```

for any natural numbers a,b,c,d.

You want to find the (one of the) subsets with the max. gcd. According to the rules above, one of this subsets has exactly two elements (given that the whole set has at least two elements). So the first optimization is to throw the subset generation away and make something like

```
max = 0
for all set elements "a"
{
    for all set elements "b"
    {
        if(gcd(a,b) > max)
            max = gcd(a,b)
    }
}
```

If that is still not enough, sort the set form the largest to the smallest element first, and for each gcd calculated in the loops, delete every set element smaller than the calculated value.

Comment: While this will definitely help, it won't be enough, because `n` can be up to `100 000`. The sort is a heuristic. There is likely a test case that breaks it.